# Create Shortcut in a phonegap app

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Create Shortcut in a phonegap app

Using this plugin:
https://github.com/jorgecis/ShortcutPlugin/tree/4c2c01cc2473f4d3af8bfb6809f5d647c0078d72

After installing it, I add a line of javascript to create it:

```
window.plugins.Shortcut.CreateShortcut("Text to show", successfunc, failfunc );
```

Works fine, but the problem is that whenever you enter the application code runs. The first says that the shortcut was created successfully, but the following times he says that the shortcut already exists, which is true.

Is there another way to add the shortcut or check if it exists so that the code is not run?

Comment: Nobody knows anything about it?

Comment: Did you found any solution? cause the below localStorage way is little bit dirty..

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your code inside a condition checking if it has already been run. For example, with localStorage:

```
if (!localStorage.getItem('shortcut')) {
    window.plugins.Shortcut.CreateShortcut("Text to show", successfunc, failfunc);
    localStorage.setItem('shortcut', true);
}
```